# Why does this generate "Undefined" when I tell it to generate a message if it doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why does this error occur when I press the button (without a string to search) or if I press the button multiple times calling the function?

[image]

I understand it as it should generate an error to the console if some of the parameters are undefined and to show everything if it works.

```
const searchPokemon = () => {
    api.get(`pokemon/${search}`.toLowerCase()).then((response) => {
      response == undefined
        ? console.log("Error")
        : setPokemon({
            name: response.data.name,
            height: response.data.height,
            weight: response.data.weight,
            img: response.data.sprites.front_default,
            id: response.data.id,
            type: response.data.types[0].type.name,
            type2: response.data.types[1]?.type.name,
          });
```

How can I go around this to solve it and why doesn't it react the way I think?

Comment: The issue is that you're trying to access `front_default` on `undefined`. That means that `response.data.sprites` is `undefined`, but you're not checking for that. You're only checking that `response` is `undefined`. You haven't checked `response.data.spriites`.

Comment: Clearly `response.data.sprites` comes back as `undefined` from the API call. Why is impossible to say for us, with this little information.

Answer (score 0):

You only check if the response is undefined. But in fact, the problem is that **response.data.sprites** is undefined. So you should check that each nested field you access to set pokemon is undefined or not.

Comment: Hey Dimitri,
Thanks for your response.
How can I check it within the setState, I've tried this " setPokemon({
            name: response.data.name,
            height: response.data.height,
            weight: response.data.weight,
            img: response.data.sprites?.front_default, : console.log('error;'),
            id: response.data.id,
            type: response.data.types[0].type.name,
            type2: response.data.types[1]?.type.name,
          });" but it doesn't seem to work.

How can I check each response?

Comment: Faith already replied. You can just use optional chaining and provide some default image (no_image_default) if sprites is undefined: setPokemon {... img: response.data.sprites?.front_default ?? no_image_default }

Answer (score 0):

You can change it

```js
const searchPokemon = () => {
    api.get(`pokemon/${search}`.toLowerCase()).then((response) => {
        response == undefined ? console.log("Error") : setPokemon({
          name: response.data.name,
          height: response.data.height,
          weight: response.data.weight,
          img: response.data.sprites?.front_default,
          id: response.data.id,
          type: response.data.types[0].type.name,
          type2: response.data.types[1]?.type.name
        });
    });
}
```